# Rewriting rule modification when moving wordpress host

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, plesk

I have a local Wordpress website stored in `localhost/wpdeal/` and it's working well, here's the content of it's root `.htaccess` file :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wpdeal/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wpdeal/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

When I moved the website to an online host (GoDaddy Windows Parallels Plesk) with `"mydomain.com"` and changed the .htaccess file accordingly to :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I'm getting a `404 error` when I try to access to the website pages except for the home page. Is something wrong with my new `.htaccess` file? Did I miss something else? It's been many hours that I'm struggling with that issue so any help will be highly appreciated!

**Update:** I've added a PHP script that check if mod_rewrite is enabled by the server :

```
<?php 
 if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_MOD_REWRITE'])){
     echo "Mod_Rewrite is running";
     } else {
     echo "Mod Rewrite is not running";
 }
?>
```

The response is : "Mod Rewrite is not running" .

Comment: You really need to run a tool to change the entries in your database to change the old domain. Like [this](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Comment: @Rich I already fixed those links in the the `sql` dump file using notepad before importing the database to the new host.

Comment: Notepad will not change the URLs in serialised arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallels Plesk for Windows supported only Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS), so you need to create web.config in httpdocs with similar content from the article http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/enabling-pretty-permalinks-in-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

[Search and replace](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) is indeed the way to go, don't manualy edit the htacess file.

Comment: Do you mean I don't have to edit htacess file at all even if it contains the old path "localhost/projects"?

Comment: Indeed, the .htaccess will get fixed automatically by Wordpress when the path name is changed in the database.